# ¿Cómo cambio el usuario que aparece en las licencias de Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

He tratado de modificar el nombre de usuario que aparee en las licencias de mi código cada que creo una clase, pero no he hallado como.

De momento intenté dar click derecho en el nodo raíz de mi proyecto y abrir la ventana de propiedades, ir a La opción "License Headers" y ver que en la plantilla dice algo así como

```
${licensePrefix}Copyright (C) ${date?date?string("yyyy")} ${project.organization!user}.
```

¿Cómo modifico el valor de esa variable `${project.organization!user}`?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente abre Tools > Templates

[image: Opción Templates en netbeans]

Eso te abrirá el Template Manager, en él da click en el botón "Settings"

[image: Botón setting del Template Manager]

En ese archivo properties que te abrirá agregas lo siguiente

```
user=Tu Nombre Completo <tu_correo at tu_dominio.com>
```

De esa manera se reconocerá para cada nuevo archivo.

Comment: Si necesitan cambiar las licencias que estaban antes usen el plugin [License Changer](https://www.codejava.net/ides/netbeans/how-to-update-license-header-for-java-files-in-netbeans)